# hide empty attribute group from products attribute tab

Tags: php, product-attribute, html

i did some coding to group the product attributes on frontend and show their groups names above theme like this:

- attgroup 1

  - attribute 1
  - attribute 2
  - ...
- attgroup 2

  - attribute 3
  - attribute 4
  - ...

this is my groupview.phtml (atributes.phtml alternative) content:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-additional">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; ?>
    <div class="attributesgroups-title">
        <h3 style="margin:0; color:white;"><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
        </div>
        <table style="border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;" class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
            <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/attributes/'.$_data['code'].'.png')?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>" /><span class="separator">|</span><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

and this is my groupview.php:

```
<?php 

class Webguys_AttributesAsGroup_Block_Groupview extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_product = null;

    function getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->_product) {
            $this->_product = Mage::registry('product');
        }
        return $this->_product;
    }

    public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
    {
        $data = array();
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
//            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {

                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                // TODO this is temporary skipping eco taxes
                if (is_string($value)) {
                    if (strlen($value) && $product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                        if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price') {
                            $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value,true);
                        }

                        $group = 0;
                        if( $tmp = $attribute->getData('attribute_group_id') ) {
                            $group = $tmp;
                        }

                        $data[$group]['items'][ $attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                           'label' => $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
                           'value' => $value,
                           'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                        );

                        $data[$group]['attrid'] = $attribute->getId();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Noch Titel lesen
        foreach( $data AS $groupId => &$group ) {
            $groupModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')->load( $groupId );
            $group['title'] = $groupModel->getAttributeGroupName();
        }

        return $data;
    }    


}
```

i customized my code to hide attributes with empty values from this tab. its working fine but their group titles are still showing. i want to hide group titles of attribute groups which doesn't contain any filled attributes.

[image: hide att group]

Comment: Can you include in your post some screenshots with empty attribute groups to understand you more clearly

Comment: @zhartaunik I added image. can you check it out please?

Comment: @Moh3n Did you found a working solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Jelle Yes its working

Comment: @Moh3n Can you provide the working code? Because I'm looking for the same solution as you asked for, but give solution is not working. I'm getting things like ' [47] => array(4) { ["items"] => array(2) { ["licensed_by"] => array(3) { ["label"] => string(19)...'

Comment: @Jelle what do you get for empty attributes? write one of them here.
for example:
["licensed_by"] => array(3) {
        ["label"] => string(19) "licensed by"
        ["value"] => string(6) "No"
        ["code"] => string(11) "licensed_by"

Comment: @Moh3n I get a lot of values like that. But the page does not load with the correct code. Did you change something on the code below to make it work? I just want to hide the attribute group when it does not have any value.

Comment: @Jelle you must comment out "<?php Zend_Debug::dump($_additionalgroup); ?>" and "Zend_Debug::dump($_additional);"

Comment: @Moh3n Also tried that, but that does not work. The empty attribute group is still displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that what you should do is when your generating the array in getAdditionalData, you pre define if the group has actually got any values worth displaying the group. Then in the template you can do a simple check before actually rendering any of the block.

```
    public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
    {
        $data = array();
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        //Zend_Debug::dump($attributes);
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
//            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            // Zend_Debug::dump($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() );
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {

                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);


                // TODO this is temporary skipping eco taxes
                if (is_string($value)) {
                    if (strlen($value) && $product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                        if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price') {
                            $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value,true);
                        }

                        $group = 0;
                        if( $tmp = $attribute->getData('attribute_group_id') ) {
                            $group = $tmp;
                        }

                        $data[$group]['items'][ $attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                            'label' => $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
                            'value' => $value,
                            'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                        );

                        // If there has been a value set above, we know this group is worth showing.
                        if(strlen($data[$group]['items'][$attribute->getAttributeCode()]['value']) && $data[$group]['items'][$attribute->getAttributeCode()]['value'] !== "No") {

                            /* Optionally, 
                             * If you require No as a valid option, verify those attributes here. 
                             * @example 
                             * if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == "yesNoOption") {
                             * $data[$group]['values_exist'] = true;
                             * } else {
                             * $data[$group]['values_exist'] = false;
                             * } 
                             */
                            // Set the group to record that it has values
                            $data[$group]['values_exist'] = true;
                        }
                        $data[$group]['attrid'] = $attribute->getId();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Noch Titel lesen
        foreach( $data AS $groupId => &$group ) {
            $groupModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')->load( $groupId );
            $group['title'] = $groupModel->getAttributeGroupName();

        }

        return $data;
    }
```

With the above modification, you will then be able to in your template do a quick check on it and skip to the next record before doing any of the html output.

```
    <?php Zend_Debug::dump($_additionalgroup); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++;
        Zend_Debug::dump($_additional);
        if(!isset($_additional['values_exist']) || $_additional['values_exist'] !== true) {
            continue;
        }

    ?>
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

I setup an example environment locally to debug why you might be experiencing continued problem. I noticed on one of them I was getting a default value of "No" back for the attribute. I have updated the code above to handle this - if there is no value, or the value returned is "No" then it will make it so that they are considered not valid.

If however you have attributes which do actually have the value of "No" as a legitimate display option you'll need to modify the code (look at the comment I've made in the Block for an example).

Comment: can you please check my answer. i have putted my edited files for you. i changed my files with your method but now all my group titles are hidden. i just want empty ones to get hide.

Comment: @Moh3n I have updated my answer with debug statements where I was suggesting. I think whats happening is your getting a default value back, which means the check for string length is not correctly identifing it - ie "No" is a valid response.

Comment: its not working. its getting  something like this in additional tab: '
  [47] => array(4) {
    ["items"] => array(2) {
      ["licensed_by"] => array(3) {
        ["label"] => string(19)...'

Comment: @Moh3n it means your getting a valid response then for ones that you believe should be invalid. Please post the full result so we can see what other conditions are needing to be detected. And highlight the ones which you believe are incorrect.

Comment: would you pleas check my debug report please?

Comment: It looks to me like your getting a NO back instead of No, so if you update the value to check against that in the block then you should be fine.

Comment: i'm a little bit confused. can you explain by detailes pleas?

Comment: @Moh3n you have this: "value"] => string(6) "NO" << We are checking against No, (No != NO)

Comment: that 'NO' is translated by me from another language

Comment: Hi @Moh3n ok if the value is translated, then that might be why its not being picked up - in the line in the block where we're checking against No, put in the untranslated version since thats what it is comparing against.